# Mocking data for Angular2/typescript with my own model type properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in the Angular2 world. For learning Angular I followed different tutorials and now I try to build a shop to learn more. But i get stuck right away.

I'm trying to get this model in to Angular:
[image]

But I'm not succeeding. I get different errors like.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined and error
>   TS2322: Type '{ ... }' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.Type ...

This is what i got so far:

Product-type-attribute-model

```
export class ProductTypeAttribute {
id: number;
name: string;
content: string;
}
```

Product-type-model

```
import { ProductTypeAttribute } from './product-type-attribute.model';

export class ProductType {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    attributeTypes: ProductTypeAttribute[];
}
```

Product-model

```
import { ProductType} from './product-type.model';

export class Product  {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
    price: number;
    type: ProductType;
}
```

Mock-product

```
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { ProductType } from './product-type.model';
import { ProductTypeAttribute } from './product-type-attribute.model';

export const productTypeAttributes: ProductTypeAttribute[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Kleur',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    }
];

export const productTypeAttributes2: ProductTypeAttribute[] = [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Kleur',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: 'test',
        content: 'test'
    }
];

export const productType: ProductType =
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Type 1',
        description: 'Description of type 1',
        attributeTypes: productTypeAttributes
    };

export const productType2: ProductType =
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Type 2',
        description: 'Description of type 2',
        attributeTypes: productTypeAttributes2
    };

export const products: Product[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Product 1',
        description: 'Description of product 1',
        image: 'https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8',
        price: 15.15,
        type: productType
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Product 2',
        description: 'Description of product 2',
        image: 'https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8',
        price: 15.15,
        type: productType
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Product 3',
        description: 'Description of product 3',
        image: 'https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8',
        price: 15.15,
        type: productType2
    }
];
```

Product-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Product } from './../shared/product.model';
import { products } from './../shared/mock-products';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(products);
    }

    getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
        return this.getProducts().then(products => products.find(product => product.id === id));
    }
}
```

Product-component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './../shared/product.model';
import { ProductService } from './../product/product.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    template: require('./product.component.html'),
    providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    product: Product;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    getProduct(): void {
        this.productService.getProduct(1).then(product => this.product = product);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getProduct();
    }
}
```

Product HTML

```
<div class="product">
<div class="header">
        <h1>{{product?.name}}</h1>
        <h4></h4>
</div>

<figure>
    <img src="{{product?.image}}">
</figure>

<section>
    <p>{{product?.description}}</p>
    <details>
        <summary>Product Features</summary>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let productAttribute of product?.type?.attributeTypes">
                {{productAttribute?.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </details>
    <button>Buy Now</button>
</section>
```

I hope I explained my problem well and that you guys can help me out here.

**UPDATE**
[image]

*UPDATE**
Okay, now things are getting crazy.
When i do this

```
export const products: ({ id: number;description: string;image: string;price: number;type: Object } |
{ id: number;name: string;description: string;image: string;price: number;type: Object })[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    description: "Description of product 1",
    image: "https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8",
    price: 15.15,
    type: productType
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Product 2",
    description: "Description of product 2",
    image: "https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8",
    price: 15.15,
    type: productType
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Product 3",
    description: "Description of product 3",
    image: "https://www.google.nl/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2Fresources%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Fangular2%2Fangular.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fangular.io%2F&docid=bJoyJcb-C12SHM&tbnid=G_BYSyR7DGpqqM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=800&bih=1060&biw=1060&q=angular2&ved=0ahUKEwjdrq6it87RAhUEExoKHdXlAYIQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8",
    price: 15.15,
    type: productType2
}
```

It gives no errors, but does not show the name.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. So I have to use constructor in my models or change them to an interface? Or should I use a constructor in my mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually tested your code, there only seems to be async problem. Try using the safe operator: `?` (otherwise also called elvis-operator) like so:

```
<h1>{{product?.name}}</h1>
```

The other option is to use `*ngIf` like so:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product">{{product.name}}</h1>
```

More about the elvis-operator [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0). This comes really handy in Angular (2) apps, since we are constantly dealing with async operations, since (usually) the view is rendered before data is received.

If you prefer `*ngIf` this also works, app won't throw error since the code you have wrapped inside it, is only rendered when there is data present, in this case in your `product` object.

### Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Czj3y80IM3ntL2nPBZzT?p=preview)

You could change your classes to interfaces instead, so:

```
export interface Product  {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
    price: number;
    type: ProductType;
}
```

or add constructor to your classes:

```
export class Product  {
    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public name: string,
      public description: string,
      public image: string,
      public price: number,
      public type: ProductType
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Elvis did help me. But the second error is stil showing up. TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined and error TS2322: Type '{ ... }' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.Type ...

Comment: Okay, well where are you trying to use `description`, doesn't show in the code you provided?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, updated my answer with a working plunker with the code you have provided, please refer to that :)

Comment: Please see my update. I get the same results, but whit that error

Comment: Try changing to Interface instead (look updated answer). I don't know really what to do more, the code you have provided works as should. You would have to reproduce your issue in a plunker, since with the code you have given the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I tried your sollutions but stil an error. If you can see my last update. Very strange whats going on

Comment: As said, you would have to have to reproduce this issue with a plunker yourself, as I have copied your code EXACTLY as you have provided, and as you can see in the plunker, there is no error in the code you have provided. Reproduce it, please, you cannot be helped further with this unless you do that.

Comment: You were right the whole time. The problem was, I geus, rebuilding the project. It had cached something an therefor gave the error. Now its working like a charm. Thank you very much :D